# bash script how to debug a mysql statement into a while read loop

Tags: mysql, bash, mariadb

I would like to debug a mysql statement being passed into `while read` loop

```
while read -r tmpFile;
    do
        chomped_line=${tmpFile}
        myVar+=("$chomped_line")

    done < <(mysql -u ${myUsr} -p${myPass} -h ${myH}  -D ${myD} --batch --xml<${mySqlStm})
```

if the mysql is valid, the `while read` works as expected. But when we have an error I cannot get a debug.

How can i get an copy of the error message into a log file?

Comment: check your code first at https://shellcheck.net .You'll need to include a proper reference to your shell as the first line of code, usually `#!/bin/bash` will work. Good luck.

Comment: Using shell scripts to run SQL is tempting _at first_.  But you are finding one of many reasons not to do that.  Can your task be done with a single "source" command in the commandline tool 'mysql'?

Comment: @RickJames, we have a multi line mysql `else if` using delimiter, so needs to be passed via var.

Comment: @artvanderlay - a bash `else if`?

Comment: @RickJames, it is a multi line mysql statement containing multiple `else if` plus `commit` that is dynamically created in the bash script, so is passed via a var

Comment: Is `mySqlStm` a variable containing a sql statement? You are using it as a file. It won't work if it contains e.g. `mySqlStm='SELECT * FROM ...;'`

Comment: An `IF` _statement_ cannot be used except in a Stored Routine.

Comment: Execute your `mysql` command with the query and send the output to a file (`>output`).  Do the same with the error (`2>errors`).  Get your while to read the output file.  If there are errors, you will see them in the errors file.  You will also be able to check the return code from the `mysql` command (`$?`)